# Approach to use git with two masters

Tags: git

We have two customers (and counting) which share like 80% code of a project, the main differences are like images, config files and some HTML. There is nothing like a master, because without the individually data the project could not run.

What would be the best practice to handle this scenario with git? Is it possible to use git flow somehow?

Currently we just have 4 branches:

```
customer1_dev -> customer1_master
customer2_dev -> customer2_master
```

We are Cherry-picking most of the commits between those.

Comment: Why don't you separate using *config*, rather than a separate repo?

Comment: We started out like that but had a few scripts to run before to load the different images & icons, language files and configurations before starting to develop. Before the build we had to change another few files.
That didn't felled right :(
And we had to save all files for both customers in one repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary option when using Git for managing code-bases in this scenario is to branch from the common code-base and then maintain separate branches for each customer (and limit commits to those customer branches to their specific stuff). **All common development should occur in the main-line branch**.

Then when you're ready to build a release candidate for a specific customer, switch to their `branch` and do a: `git merge master` into that customer's branch. That will bring in all the changes from the main line into your customer specific branch.

You could do a `rebase` rather than merge. But that is less advantageous because it can make it harder to track down a root cause for a bug if one pops up in a customer branch that is not in the main-line branch. But either a `merge` or `rebase` into a customer branch should provide a good workflow for the situation you described.

Comment: How could I test development if the code can't run on the master?

Comment: Couple approaches, but I would `branch` from the customer's branch, merge  `master` into the new branch and then execute the test cases. If the tests pass, `rebase` that branch onto the customer branch it came from.

Answer (score 1):

Your case sounds like you have one repository/service/code base which should be forked for two clients. I would suggest to create a master branch which contains that 80% of the code (the common part). Client branches would rebase themselves to this master branch when there is a change. 
Ideally, you'd separate these into 3 repos and client repos would be forks of those.

Personally, I wouldn't depend on git for different configs and media. It would be safer to use configs or some sort of cms.

Comment: How would you distinguish between the config-files and images? Something like an environment variable? How could I handle the different parts in files like package.json?

Comment: For media, I'd differentiate it with environment variables + different directories (paths) for media. If they have to depend on different packages, I'd recommend a monorepo structure with yarn workspaces + lerna.

Comment: I think I could try it again with the environment vars, but the issue with the package.json still bothers me, because the customers insist in different names and descriptions..

Comment: Check this approach: https://medium.com/hy-vee-engineering/creating-a-monorepo-with-lerna-yarn-workspaces-cf163908965d

Comment: Thanks :)
I tried it with https://github.com/nrwl/nx (easier with an angular project) but it's not fitting in with the project.